# Is the name of Earth's Master Mage spelled "Eldrich" or "Eldritch"?

Tags: edition-comparison, mutants-and-masterminds

Someone on the Discord asked this question, and I was surprised to find that the answer didn't seem clear.

In the 1e *Freedom City* book, Adrian Eldrich was introduced as Earth's Master Mage, who goes by Eldrich. It's the same in 2E (only two mentions of "Adrian Eldritch" in *Freedom City*, and consistently Eldrich in the 2E free adventure, "Crisis on Christmas" and the 2E *Book of Magic*). 3E, on the other hand, it's almost universally "Adrian Eldritch", going by "Eldritch" except for one mention of "Eldritch (Adrian Eldrich)" in *Freedom City*, and in the 3E version of "Crisis on Christmas", he's consistently "Adrian Eldritch". The exception I've found are the *Netherwar* adventures, which almost universally refer to "Eldrich" as both his last name and his hero name.

I'm going to ask Steve Kenson (the creator of Freedom City and many of its characters) on Mutants and Masterminds Monday. My suspicion is that the *Freedom City* book and the "Crisis on Christmas" adventure fell prey to spellchecking software and just no one has gotten around to fixing it (admittedly, slightly complicated by that the word "eldritch" is sometimes used not referring to the Master Mage).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a question about designer intent

Comment: as a problem that runs through all the MM books, I think it's an Edition comparison.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to Steve Kenson](https://youtu.be/xzPnW61Y-kQ?t=613), the name was supposed to be Adrian Eldrich, who went by the name of Eldritch as a superhero, but from the beginning, they ran into issues with no one keeping the name consistent.

> The real short answer is that I thought it would be really clever if Eldrich's name sounded like the word 'eldritch' but was spelled differently. Just a small piece of advice, never do that. It's a terrible idea, because it confuses editors and other developers and other writers, and no one ever from that point on knows exactly how his name is supposed to be spelled. The original idea was that the spelling without the 't' was his actual name and the spelling with the 't' was his superhero name. And like I said, that's a terrible idea. Don't ever do that.